# Interpretation of .join()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Original code:

```
board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append("O" * 5)
print(board)
```

Why does the code print each index in its own row when you add this to the code above?

```
board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append("O" * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" " .join(row))

print_board(board)
```

Comment: this works fine on my machine `'O O O O O \n
O O O O O \n
O O O O O \n
O O O O O \n
O O O O O'`

Comment: Yea but I am wondering why there is a new line when you add the bottom code?

Comment: because you are calling `print()` multiple times. You can set [`print(…, end='')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to get rid of the newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing print in a for loop, 
everytime the loop is iterating through the row, 
it's doing a new print statement on the next line.

Think of it this way.

```
for i in range(5):
    print (i)
```

makes

```
0
1
2
3
4
```